# Does anyone know where to get the old WDM version of the toaster driver sample?

Tags: windows, driver, wdk, wdm, wdf

The current 8.x Windows driver kit samples include the toaster sample, but only implemented in KMDF and UMDF. I have a particular application that requires specialized treatment of PNP messages that I don't think will work with KMDF. Does anyone know where I can get the WDM version of toaster that used to be in the samples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and install the [7.1.0 WDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800), this WDK contains a lot of the legacy WDM samples.

Comment: I didn't think of this because WDK 8.x has the samples as a separate download.